# Show only one Register error instead of two

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I have an ASP.Net MVC site that uses ASP.Net Identity for managing users.

I use the default mechanism that the Email of the user is also his username. When a user wants to register with an Email which is already taken two error messages are shown:

- Name myEmail@gmail.com is already taken.
- Email 'myEmail@gmail.com' is already taken.

The structure of the Register form:

[image: How the Register form looks like]

HttpPost Register Method of AccountController:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var user = new ApplicationUser {UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email};
        var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            string callbackUrl =
                await SendEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user.Id, "Confirm your account");

            return View("Info");
        }
        AddErrors(result);
    }

    // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
    return View(model);
}
```

How can I only show the Email Error message to the user?

Comment: Replace your `AddErrors()` method with `ModelState.AddModelError("", String.Format("{0} is already taken", model.Email));`

Comment: Works. Just out of curiosity: How are the other Errors added? (for instance that the two password fields don't match) I thought that these were added in that method aswell. Turns out that I was wrong. @StephenMuecke

Comment: They will be added because of your validation attributes - e.g. a `[Compare]` applied to a `ConfirmPassword` property. The `DefaultModelBinder` adds the `ModelState` errors during the binding process

Comment: @StephenMuecke Oh! Forgot that. You should add this as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your `AddErrors()` method with

```
ModelState.AddModelError("", String.Format("{0} is already taken", model.Email))
```

or, if you have included `@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Email)` in the view and want the message to be associated with the form control, rather than in the summary

```
ModelState.AddModelError("Email", String.Format("{0} is already taken", model.Email))
```

Side note: You might also want to consider using a `RemoteAttribute` so that you get client side validation before submitting the form - refer [How to: Implement Remote Validation in ASP.NET MVC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg508808(VS.98).aspx) (although you should also keep the code above in (the rare) case 2 users submit the same `Email` at the same time).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, only one Error gets shown now BUT when the password fails trough the validation, the same error gets shown. How do I fix it?

Comment: You can add multiple errors - e.g. `ModelState.AddModelError("", "Another error")` but you have not shown anything relating to password validation so I cannot guess what your doing. Are you referring to validation attributes applied to your model property?

Comment: I now fixed it with an if clause. If it is the email error I do what you did and if not, I call the AddErrors method.